# Python function return 2 lists

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, tuples

I have a function that creates two lists. I want the function to return the two lists as `[], []`.

Here is the code. This returns a list that look like this `[[], []]`, close but still not what I want.

```
def create_xy_lst(start, length, step, up, down):
    new_list = []
    new_list.append(create_x_lst(start, length, step))
    new_list.append(create_y_lst(start, length, up, down))
    return new_list
```

Then I tried a different approach. This returns `([], [])` which is a tuple.

```
def create_xy_lst(start, length, step, up, down):

    x = (create_x_lst(start, length, step))
    y = (create_y_lst(start, length, up, down))
    return x, y
```

How can I make the function return `[], []`?

Python 2.7

Comment: So, what is the problem with that? Maybe you can tell us, what exactly you are trying to.

Comment: Returning the two lists as `[],[]` *is* returning a `tuple`.  You can't return two things from a function.

Comment: You can't have a function return two things. A `tuple` is as close as you can get.

Comment: @thefourtheye I want to use the output in another function

Comment: So use tuple unpacking when you call the function. `x, y = create_xy_lst(args)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[], []` is a tuple. `()` is simple there for syntax, let me demonstrate:

```
>>> hello = 1,
>>> hello
(1,)
>>> cheese = [1,2,3], [6,7,8]
>>> cheese
([1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8])
```

As you can see the `,` is what makes a tuple.

And you can unpack them like so:

```
>>> a, b = [1,2], [3,4]
>>> a
>>> [1,2]
>>> b
>>> [3,4]
```

So, in your function:

```
x, y = create_xy_lst(start, length, step, up, down)
```

This is also a neat trick (if you're in Python 3) if you have more than one list in the tuple:

```
>>> a, *b = [2], [4,5,6], [10]
>>> a
>>> [2]
>>> b
>>> ([4,5,6], [10])
```

If however, you simple want to return one `list`, you can do this:

```
return x + y
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7 - Should have put that in the question.

Answer (score 7):

`[], []` *is a tuple*:

```
>>> [], []
([], [])
```

The comma makes the value a tuple, not the parenthesis.

Returning `x, y` is the correct way to return multiple values.

You can unpack tuples into multiple variables:

```
x, y = [], []
```

and this works just fine for function return values too:

```
x, y = create_xy_lst(...)
```

Unpacking in an assignment is not limited to just tuples; it works with any sequence:

```
char1, char2, char3 = 'foo'
```

Comment: x, y = create_xy_lst(...)   ------- Will this make x and y the same list?

Comment: Only if you return the same list twice.

Comment: @user320: no, Python expects the right-hand side to produce a sequence of exactly two values. It then assigns those values to the names on the left, from left to right, one value to one name each.

Comment: @user320: if your function returns a tuple of two lists, `x` and `y` are each assigned one list from that tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I like Python3's unpacking a lot :)

Comment: @Games: You mean the addition of the wildcard target? Because multiple-target assignment has been around for a long time already :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup. Me likes stars! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
def returnNumbers():
    return 1, 2

first, second = returnNumbers()
print first, second
```

It will print

```
1 2
```

You can simply return a tuple and unpack the values like shown in the example.

You can even check the type of data returned by the function like this

```
print type(returnNumbers())
```

it will print

```
<type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second try is (mostly) the right way (you just don't need the parenthesis around your function calls).

I'm guessing you're retrieving your results like this:

```
foo = create_xy_list(...)
```

try this instead:

```
foo, bar = create_xy_list(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a tuple but you are rejecting the idea that it should be a tuple so here is another idea. You could turn it into a generator.

```
def create_xy_lst(start, length, step, up, down):

    yield create_x_lst(start, length, step))
    yield create_y_lst(start, length, up, down))
```

which will only yield 1 list per query.

```
val = create_xy_lst(a,b,c,d,e)
print(val.next()) #first list
print(val.next()) #second list
```

or you could loop over it

```
for val in create_xy_lst(a,b,c,d,e):
    print(val)
```